# ¿Por qué la configuración del log4j.properties no está siendo usada?

Tags: maven, tomcat, struts, log4j

Tengo un proyecto mavenizado corriendo en tomcat *8.5*.

Tengo una configuración según una normativa específica para los logs. Estoy usando log4j versión *1.2.14* y tengo mi *log4j.properties* en mi localización de recursos (también he probado a cambiar dicha localización del fichero), dicha localización es

```
src/main/filteredResources.
```

Para otros proyectos en los que he tenido que hacer lo mismo, me ha funcionado sin problemas, pero claro, usaba spring y tenía que inicializar el bean con la llamada a la ruta del fichero. Sin ello no mostraba log por consola ni creaba el fichero logs en la ruta especificada. Para este proyecto se utiliza struts y por lo que he investigado, con añadir el properties en la raíz sería suficiente, pero esto no ha tenido éxito tampoco.

Lo extraño es que me pinta unos logs por consola sin tener nada configurado, pero no son en el formato que deseo y tengo en el *log4j.properties*.

Posterior a esto, usé el parámetro:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

Esto lo pinta en mi local, pero necesito que siga funcionando una vez desplegado en otros entornos. ¿Existe una alternativa real a esto?

¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Por favor no resumas las cosas. Indica en detalle qué carpeta tiene el archivo, el contenido del mismo y cómo está estructurado.

Comment: ya intentaste poner tu archivo en src/main/resources ? PD: si no usas spring que usas?

Comment: @RuslanLópez si que lo añadí pero sin éxito, la alternativa como tal, aunque no sea lo mismo, es struts con tiles, voy a añadir esto último que veo que se me pasó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente se añadió en el `web.xml` un `context-param` haciendo referencia a la localización del fichero:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Posteriormente, en el `contextListener` se añadió lo siguiente para hacer el fichero y que lo pintase según mi configuración:

```
ServletContext context = arg0.getServletContext();
String log4jConfigFile = context.getInitParameter("log4j-config-location");
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("") + File.separator + log4jConfigFile;
PropertyConfigurator.configure(fullPath);
```

Con esto conseguí que reconociese mi configuración.

Añado como información adicional, que al tratarse de un proyecto modulado era necesario hacer esto, pues por este motivo no reconocía el log4j.properties estuviese el fichero donde estuviese.